# automap List of complex type to List of complex type using automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public class SourceExamModel
{
    public int ExamId { get; set; }      

    public List<SectionModel> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class  DesiationExamModel
{
public in ExamId {get;set;}
public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SectionModel> DestSections
{
    get
    {
    }
    set
    {
    }
}
```

What I tried:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<CrmMapper.SourceExamModel, CrmMapper.DestiationExamModel>()
    .ForMember(v => v.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
    .ForMember(v => v.DestSections, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SourceSections));      
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var source = new ExamModel();
var dest = mapper.Map<SourceExamModel, CrmMapper.DestiationExamModel>(source);
```

Can ayone help me how to map list of comple objects o los of complex objects

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming half of your example code is simple spelling mistakes, you pretty much have it working.

1. If the properties on the source and destination are named the same, you don't have to explicitly map them.
2. Your `source` in your example doesn't make sense, it needs the correct object and data.

Here's my attempt at a working example you can copy past into a console application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceExamModel, DestinationExamModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DestSections, c => c.MapFrom(src => src.Sections))
        );

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var source = new SourceExamModel
        {
            ExamId = 1,
            Sections = new List<SectionModel> { new SectionModel { SectionId = 1 }, new SectionModel { SectionId = 2 } }
        };

        var destination = mapper.Map<SourceExamModel, DestinationExamModel>(source);
    }
}

public class SourceExamModel
{
    public int ExamId { get; set; }

    public List<SectionModel> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationExamModel
{
    public int ExamId { get; set; }

    public List<SectionModel> DestSections { get; set; }
}

public class SectionModel
{
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
}
```